# Why would SMTP authentication for Office 365 fail for one domain, but not for another?

Tags: c#, smtp, mailkit, smtp-auth

I have some straightforward C# code (on .NET 4.8) using MailKit to send mail via Office 365:

```
var messageToSend = new MimeMessage
{
    Sender = new MailboxAddress("Data Catalyst Site", "xxx@xxx.xx"),
    Subject = "New Data Catalyst Site Contact",
    Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = $"<html>{builder.ToString()}</html>" }
};

messageToSend.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("DataCatalyst", "yyy@xxx.xx"));

using (var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

    await smtp.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    await smtp.AuthenticateAsync("xxx@xxx.xx", "********");
    await smtp.SendAsync(messageToSend);
    await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true);

};
```

We have multiple Office 365 domains. If I use any mailbox from one domain, this works fine. If I use any mailbox from another, it fails with:

`SmtpCommandException: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LNXP265CA0036.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]`

I've tested with our usual outbound mail account, my own account, and a new account/mailbox created just for the test. In each case I know the password well, and have logged in to the office portal to verify this.

Since the fail is across multiple mailboxes, this feels like a setting somewhere in office configuration - but where? Or what else are we missing?

Comment: Absolutely!!! A Corporate Network with an Outlook Mail Server will forward all emails using port 587 to a proxy server.  So emails to gmail will get blocked.  The proxy server will verify emails using a corporate Password server and will reject a user name and password.  So you must set default credentials to true instead of using username/password.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand it, or that it is fully relevant here. We're not trying to send to gmail. And it cannot be true that we must not *ever* use username/password, because this works fine for the other domain.

Comment: gmail was just an example. What credential are allowed depends on domain settings.